# Adding parameters to a Volley PUT request - Android

Tags: android, parameters, android-volley, put

I have been using volley Library in my app for making network connections. I am able to append parameters in GET and POST requests and both are working fine but couldn't figure out how to do that in a PUT request. I am always getting a "`415- status{ Unsupported media type} -result { Invalid content Type}`" Error.  Did a lot of searching but none worked.

This is what I have tried

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleyRequests.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
    String uri = "https://myURI";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, uri, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Log.d("server response",response);
            userCallBack.done(response);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String>  headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("secret_apikey", "xxxxxxx");
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("userid", "013");

            params.put("sale_amount","2000");
            return params;
        }};
   requestQueue.add(request);
```

I tried adding the parameters in a byte array as well. this is the code.

```
 @Override
 public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            byte[] b = null;
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                obj.put("userid", "013");            
                obj.put("sale_amount","2000");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("Excep", String.valueOf(e));
            }
            try {
                Log.i("json", obj.toString());
                b = obj.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.d("Excep", String.valueOf(e));
        }

            return b;
        }
```

I cannot replace it with a POST or get request because because the API I am calling accepts only PUT requests. Kindly help.

Comment: Are you PUTting to a web service you control or a third party? I don't see where you execute the request. Can you check the logs from that web service?

Comment: I have updated the code. No it is not a web service i control. Any other ideas?? Thanks.